# What SSH server does the Raspberry Pi use?

Tags: ssh, server

I really like the simplicity and power of the Raspberry Pi's SSH server - no messing around with impossible-to-create text files containing the username and some arbitrary hash of the password that's been salted by the IP and only works for certain domains unless you have a certificate... you get the idea. Either way, after attempting to puzzle out OpenSSH for a while on my Ubuntu box, I gave up.

What I'd like to know is, what SSH server does the Pi use, and can I get it on my other boxes? What I'd like to do is have my Pi set up as sort of an access hub to my other computers:

```
james@FriendComputer~$ ssh pi@98.81.0.0
pi@98.81.0.0's password:
pi@98.81.0.0~$ ssh james@192.168.0.0
james@192.168.0.0's password:
james@192.168.0.0~$
```

..if you look at the above diagram, you'll get an idea of what I'm talking about. Either way, OpenSSH proved to be too much of a bother to deal with, so I want whatever the Pi's got.

Comment: "whatever the Pi's got" == openssh

Comment: if you're running Raspbmc then it's Dropbear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"can I get it on my other boxes?"

You mention you have an Ubuntu box, but you say "other boxes" so I presume you have further machines you'd like it on. Openssh server and client (as existing answer explains very well), is whats on the Pi. It is available on just about every other Unix/Linux and Mac too. It is also available via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on Windows if you wish to ssh into a Windows machine and get a near-equivalent of a terminal to run commands in.

For Linux machines, you should be able to use the normal software package install process to install openssh-server (the name may vary slightly between distributions/OSs). The default setup ought to be suitable; copying/generating keys is the hardest part.

If you need help setting up openssh server on your other machine(s), you should write a specific question giving information and details on the problems you are having there or what you want to change from the default configuration (or google existing help for that).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which distribution you use. The most popular one, Raspbian, is a recompilation of Debian distribution. Ubuntu is based on Debian but has a lot of changes on top of it.

OpenSSH is default SSH server in Debian and so is in Raspbian. So if you are using Raspbian, you are using OpenSSH, unless you changed it.

I have no idea what "impossible-to-create" text file you are talking about. There shouldn't be anything like that on Ubuntu. It should work the same (or almost the same) as on Raspberry Pi.

There is nothing else you have to do to setup your Raspberry Pi as an "SSH hub" if you want to use passwords for authentication. It may be more convenient to setup SSH keys on Raspberry Pi and then configure all your SSH servers for keys authentication. You can find a lot of information about setting this up so instead of describing it here I will only give you a hint on the two commands that should be used: `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`.